# How did Evernote implement their Clearly Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, evernote

[Clearly](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/clearly.php) is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iooicodkiihhpojmmeghjclgihfjdjhj) developed by Evernote which makes blog posts, articles and webpages clean and easy to read. Clearly eliminates all distractions (header, footer, navigation, ads ...) from page to have seamless view! How does it work under the hood taken in consideration that page structure differs from site to another one?

Comment: Perhaps try asking them? This isn't really a concrete programming question.

Comment: I think this is a constructive question and can be moved meta as I and maybe even others are intrigued on how a frame isolates required content....

Comment: This is a great question. Figuring out how the chrome extension works internally in JS is very programming question

Comment: What, why is this closed???

Comment: According to http://www.labnol.org/software/view-source-of-chrome-extension/21284/, you can see the source of a chrome extension. May be it will help?

Comment: I still need an answer for this...

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP Did you try looking at clearly source ?